# Error building/linking ns3 network simulator with OpenFlow

Tags: c, linux, linker, simulator, ns-3

I'm trying to build ns-3.24.1 on Fedora 22 inside a VirtualBox VM. I am running:

./waf configure --enable-examples --enable-tests --with-openflow=/path/to/openflow --with-pybindgen=/path/to/pybindgen
./waf build

I want to use OpenFlow, so I downloaded and configured/built the OFSID according to [these instructions](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.24/models/html/openflow-switch.html#building-ofsid) before running the above configure command. The output from the configure step shows OpenFlow as 'enabled'.

The ns-3.24.1 build proceeds normally until it gets to the following step and spits out the subsequent error:

```
[2291/2493] Linking build/src/openflow/examples/ns3.24.1-openflow-switch-debug
./libns3.24.1-openflow-debug.so: undefined reference to `update_checksums'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
...
```

I.e., it appears to build everything correctly but then errors on the link step.

Apparently *update_checksums* is in [...]/ns-3.24.1/src/openflow/model/openflow-interface.h; for some reason the link step doesn't know to look here for *openflow-interface.h*.

What could be causing it and what can I try to fix it? FWIW I've re-downloaded both the ns-3 and OFSID sources several times to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, there is no need to install OpenFlow/Python unless you want to use OpenFlow and/or Python for your development. It is explained in the tutorial:

> Regarding the portion about modules not built:
>
> Modules not built (see ns-3 tutorial for explanation):
> brite          click                     openflow visualizer
>
> This just means that
> some ns-3 modules that have dependencies on outside libraries may not
> have been built, or that the configuration specifically asked not to
> build them. It does not mean that the simulator did not build
> successfully or that it will provide wrong results for the modules
> listed as being built.

After the 'configure' do you see that OpenFlow is enabled?

> Under ---- Summary of optional NS-3 features: you should see:
>
> "NS-3 OpenFlow Integration     : **enabled**"

Comment: I do want to use OpenFlow. Edited question to clarify this. The configure step shows OpenFlow as 'enabled'.

Comment: And I assume that in "--with-openflow=path/to/openflow" you actually use the path that you have installed openflow, e.g. "--with-openflow=/home/toni/openflow" (where you have installed it.

Comment: Yes :-) I use the absolute path.

Comment: BTW, the file it is searching for, openflow-interface.h, is part of the ns-3 distribution (my distribution has it in ns-3.24.1/src/openflow/model), not the OFSID library.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of gcc require the following two patches to fix the linking problem reported above:
1) http://code.nsnam.org/openflow/rev/4db95a8ea718
2) http://code.nsnam.org/ns-3-dev/rev/270a1c2fb158

These patches will be included in the ns-3.25 release.

Answer (score 0):

Check your pt_act.c file in switch/ folder of the downloaded openflow distribution. If update_checksums is not defined as static function, follow @Tom Henderson's suggestion 1), which asks you to add "static" before "void inline".

```
static void inline
```

Then 1) rebuild openflow. 2) go to the position of your ns distribution, remove libns3.24.1-openflow-debug.so from build/lib . 3) configure waf and build again.